# Preserve restrictive flag when restoring Db2 database

Tags: database, db2, database-backups, db2-luw, database-restore

**Is there any way to preserve the Db2 restrictive mode setting during a database restore?**

Problem: The restrictive flag is overwritten when restoring a backup of a non-restrictive Db2 database into an existing, restrictive Db2 database.

[1] IBM Db2 - Restoring to an existing database

https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=data-existing-database

[2] IBM Db2 - A practical guide to restrictive databases

https://community.ibm.com/community/user/datamanagement/viewdocument/a-practical-guide-to-restrictive-da

Regarding [2]:

> To create a restrictive database, you need to specify the RESTRICTIVE keyword with the
> CREATE DATABASE command. Here is an example:
>
> db2 CREATE DATABASE testdb RESTRICTIVE;
>
> After the restrict_access parameter is set when the database is created, it cannot be modified. This sets the restrict_access database configuration parameter to YES.

In the practical guide [2] there is no comment regarding backup/restore indeed in the KC [1](Last udpdate 24.1.2024) it would suggest under the point

> "When restoring to an existing database, the restore utility performs the following actions: (...)"

that the restrict_access configuration parameter stays/must stay in place as set during database creation.

Tested Version: Db2 LUW 11.5 on rhel 8

Comment: This is not a programming question, maybe better suited to dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/db2 .   Apart from that, when you restore a database, I understand that the settings of the source-database need to prevail.  When you "...restore into..." you are overwriting the existing database and you only inherit the NAME/alias of the database being overwritten (but not its seed, settings etc).

Comment: thanks @mao - yes, correctly, but I would say they have to inherit all "db-static" parameters - the restrictive flag is one of them, as it is should not be possible to be changed during the runtime of the database, also not by a "restore"

Comment: @mao you're right with the dba.stackexchange.com - is there a way to move this question to it?

Comment: If the source-database is unrestricted, then any backup-image of that source-database will itself be unrestricted after a restore (regardless of restore-into, which only inherits name/alias from the database-about-to-be-overwritten).  That is how the product currently works. Your expectation is incorrect.  If in doubt, open a ticket with IBM Db2 support.

Comment: thanks a lot - the service did open a ticket and we received already a fast reply. When it is like you mention it would be good to be noted at the KT page and we'll  put in an enhancement request - and move to another restore/migration method.

Comment: Nevertheless..."restrictive mode" cannot be changed during run-/lifetime of the database => it can be changed indeed: by a "restore into"...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The expectation in the question is incorrect, a "restore ... into"  will **only** inherit the name/alias of the database that is about to be overwritten (if it exists). That is to say, `restore database... into...`  will NOT preserve **any** attributes or settings of the old database being overwritten apart from name/alias.

If the source-database  (i.e the database whose backup image is being restored) is itself unrestricted, then any restored backup-image of that source-database will itself also be unrestricted.  Similarly, if the original source database was restricted, then any restored backup-image of that restricted database will itself be restricted.

That is how the Db2-LUW product (at v11.5) currently works. There exists (currently) no generally available IBM supplied script to "convert" an unrestricted-database into a restrictive-database (or vice-versa), although that might change in future. The catalog contents (as regards authorizations and permissions) are quite different.

Comment: compared to the name/alias of the database the "restrictive mode" setting is, to be discussed but expected, static as same. And if not it "needs" to be documented.

Comment: Context: The restrictive flag is requested by the audit/controlling team for quite a time. Doing the migration from unrestrictred to restricted not by backup/restore 
involves another (and more time intensive, means more costly) request at the db service provider - or - an exception request to the audit team, which no one prefers. From db development point of view I'd offer a restore with couple of options for specific cases. But alse see the efforts.